# Finding how many numbers are divisible by a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I'm trying to figure out how I can find out how many numbers are divisible by a certain prime (eg 3) in a certain range, eg 0-10000. I think it has something to do with permutations, but I'm not really sure and kinda stuck.

Could you please point me in the right direction or so?

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is divide and throw away any remainder: $\textrm{floor}(10000/3)$

Comment: For completeness I suppose: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Floor[10000%2F3]

Answer (score 3):

For your given range there are $1+\left\lfloor \cfrac{10000}{3} \right\rfloor=1+3333=3334$ numbers divisible by $3$. This count includes the end-points of your range ($0$ and $10000$).

The notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (known as ‘the floor function’) denotes the *largest* integer *less* than or equal to $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Examples include $\lfloor7\rfloor$ = $7$, $\lfloor2.5\rfloor$ = $2$, $\lfloor\pi\rfloor$= $3$ and  $\lfloor−2.5\rfloor$ = $-3$.

Comment: I think you've not counted $0$.

Comment: @lhf Well spotted, I will assume the range is inclusive although OP did not specify, thanks.